# ASP MVC Disable display template in specific view

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Is it possible to disable the use of display template in specific view?

For example.

I have 3 views `index`,`viewdetails` and `viewdetails_2`
in shared displaytemplates I have a DateTime display template to display formatted datetime and I want to disable the datetime display template in index view.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options...

First, you can carefully plan your shared templates.  For instance, if you only need your templates in your HomeController, you can simply put DisplayTemplates in your ~/Views/Home folder.

Another option is to mark fields you want to use a different template.  This can be done with `[UIHint()]` data attributes, or you can specify template name in the Editor/DisplayFor methods.

A different option would be to use not target your template at a generic type, such as DateTime, and make this a specific DataType.  Then you can simply use it wherever you want it, and default to standard behavior otherwise.

If you want to use default processor when you have a generic template defined, there is no way that I know of to say "use the default template".  Otherwise, you just don't use EditorFor/DisplayFor, and use TextBoxFor or similar instead.